# Are the Goosebumps books connected in any way?

Tags: intertextuality, goosebumps, r-l-stine

In the *Goosebumps* series, are any of the books, except for the sequels, connected to each other? I.e. characters appearing in another book.

For instance, if Slappy the dummy appeared in the book about the girl turning into a bird, that would be a definitive answer.

Answer (score 6):

#### There are no recurring characters, except in the sequels and spin-offs.

For example, as you noted with "except for the sequels", there are recurring villains such as Slappy the dummy.

However, in the spin-off series of *Goosebumps HorrorLand*, there *are* recurring places/enemies (such as the park itself).

But in the plain *Goosebumps* series, **no**.